# SQL query with german special char and Latin1_General_CI_AS

Tags: sql, select, character

I am trying to read some entries out of a microsoft sql database.
The problem ist, that one of the columns has a name with special characters "bedürfnisse" and the entries are all in Latin1_General_CI_AS.
I need to select this column.

```
Select nameName.bedürfnisse
FROM nameName
```

This is not working. I also tried

```
Select nameName.bedürfnisse COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
FROM nameName
```

but this is also not working. How can i select this column?

Comment: Rather `nameName."bedürfnisse"`, since no dbms is tagged ANSI SQL is assumed. (Will also work with SQL Server.) But, as a general advice, avoid non-ascii characters in identifiers.

Comment: @jarlh you're right. I'm too quick to assume TSQL :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What really helped was to define UTF-8 in the connection. Its one of the option parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your column names if they contain special characters. This also includes whitespace or other non-standard ascii characters in column names.

For standard ANSI SQL the syntax to do this is:

```
SELECT nameName."bedürfnisse" 
FROM nameName
```

For SQL Server this also works:

```
SELECT nameName.[bedürfnisse]
FROM nameName
```

For MySQL, this also works:

```
SELECT nameName.`bedürfnisse`
FROM nameName
```